# Creating a preference through PreferenceManager

Tags: rally

SDK 2.0 PreferenceManager, how do I create and update a preference using PreferenceManager? Just using update method does not seem to store the value, and create is "not a function" error. TypeError: Rally.data.PreferenceManager.create is not a function.

```
//load app preferences
Rally.data.PreferenceManager.load({
    appID: this.myAppId,
    filterByUser: true,
    success: function(prefs) {
        //process prefs
        if(prefs.releases) {
        this.releaseNames = prefs.releases;
        } else {
            //first time, nothing to load so create the app preferences
            Rally.data.PreferenceManager.create({
                appID: this.myAppId,
                filterByUser: true,
                settings: {
                    releases: ""
                },
                success: function(updatedRecords, notUpdatedRecords) {
                    //yay!
                    debugger;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

//things have changed, save new app preferences
Rally.data.PreferenceManager.update({
    appID: this.myAppId,
    filterByUser: true,
    settings: {
            releases: this.releaseNames
    },
    success: function(updatedRecords, notUpdatedRecords) {
        //yay!
        debugger;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the create method is not required, the update method is all that is needed.